# Rails app inside a rack app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rack

I need to mount a rails app inside a rack app? I see lots of examples of rack apps inside of rails, but not the other way.

Answer (score 0):

By default, rails runs inside a rack app.   Just look at your config.ru